# How to transform a list of tuples to a new list that count the repetitions of every key in it?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

my problem is converting list of tupples ,that each of them contain(Key,1) ,
to count the number of appearences of every key , this list is not given and its created
by me as "list comprehensions" statement, and the solution i'm looking for must to be also in one line.I have tried some python func(like `count()`
, `sum()` or `reduce`)
but none of them work , i started with pyhton recently so most of the
syntax is new for me.

This is an example , before the counting

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (6, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (4, 1), (7, 1), (14, 1)]
```

The desired result

```
{2:2, 3:1, 4:2, 6: 1, 7: 1, 14:1}
```

This is my code until now, for make it easier for you to understand the definition

```
def q1b(input_list):
    return [(y, 1) for x in input_list if q1a(x)
 is True for y in range(1, int(x/2)+1) if x % y ==0]
```

Comment: *"and the solution i'm looking for must to be also in one line"*. Why ?

Comment: Have you perhaps entered an obfuscated code competition? Implementing functionality in "one line" of Python code may make you look clever but it can invariably be hard to maintain. Keep it simple making sure that it actually works then you can start looking at efficiencies if, indeed, there are any to be made/needed

Comment: Why does your desired output not include `1:2`?

Comment: Because that was the lecturer instructions

Answer (score 0):

With `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> my_tuples = [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (6, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (4, 1), (7, 1), (14, 1)]
>>> import itertools
>>> {k: sum(c for _, c in group) for k, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(my_tuples), key=lambda t: t[0])}
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2, 6: 1, 7: 1, 14: 1}
```

This solution doesn't use `groupby` but does have to iterate over `my_tuples` repeatedly, making it less efficient:

```
>>> {key: sum(c for k, c in my_tuples if k == key) for key in set(k for k, _ in my_tuples)}
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2, 6: 1, 7: 1, 14: 1}
```